# System not showing all 2560MB (2GB + 512MB) of the RAM

Tags: ram

heres my problem i have a 2 gig ramcard and a 512mb ram but only 2142 mb appear in total available ram how do i make it use the second card?

heres some info

```
@:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2142       1032       1109          0         31        351
-/+ buffers/cache:        649       1493
Swap:         3244        114       3129

@:~$ sudo dmidecode --type memory
[sudo] password for: 
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 4 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0015
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 128 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 1
    Locator: S1
    Bank Locator: DIMM1
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0015
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 128 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 512 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 2
    Locator: S2
    Bank Locator: DIMM2
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
```

Comment: Can you adjust how much memory is allocated for integrated video in your BIOS?

Comment: You should note that basically all modern cpus are meant to interleave data across two identical banks of ram to double the throughput, so having a mismatched set like that is bad for performance.

Answer (score 4):

This is typical to see for pretty much all operating systems, Windows, Mac, and Linux all included.  I.E. not all the RAM installed is usable.

---

Note that 2GB RAM is 2048MB RAM.  Your `free -m` shows 2142MB total RAM.  So your 512MB RAM card *is* being detected and used.  Some is just not usable, though.

---

<sub>I hate Windows with a passion, but this statement is just here as a "case in point" example.</sub>

You can see this on Windows systems, as well.  In Windows, they show you how much RAM is on the system, and how much is usable.

On my system, when I am booted into Windows, it has 8GB (8192MB) of RAM available.  However, only 7.88GB (~8069MB) is actually usable, as reported by the system.  That's at least ~122MB of RAM not usable

---

This is typical for all operating systems, though.  Of the amount of RAM you have in your system, some is not usable for whatever reasons.